# Use of zero profit condition in determining unique solution

Tags: optimization

Assume that we have a profit function of the form:
$$
\pi=pf(Q)-wl-rk
$$
where $Q$ represents total volume of output, $w$ represents wages
and $r$ represents rental rate on capital $k$. One way to choose
optimal quantities of inputs is to set up the Lagrangean, where we
obtain optimal demand functions for $l^{*}$ and $k^{*}.$ Therefafter,
one obtains for each value of $Q,$ the value of $l$ and $k$ such
that profits are maximized. In that case, we have two equations in
two unknowns, and we can solve for $l^{*}$ and $k^{*}$. Now, let
us assume that $f(.)$ exhibits constant returns to scale. In that
case, we know that:
$$
\pi=pf(Q)-wl^{*}-rk^{*}=0
$$
owing to Euler's theorem. With which other equation can the profit
function above be combined to yield the unique equilibrium values
of $l^{*}$ and $k^{*}?$ Will it be with the tangency condition between
$l^{*}$ and $k^{*}?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the technology is CRS, and the parameters are such that 0 profit is both maximal and attainable with nonzero production, then the optimal solution is not unique, any multiple of it will also be optimal.